# File not found exception in Windows Service

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, filenotfoundexception

I have written the following code in a Windows service. When I try to save the zip file, I am getting a File Not Found Exception. I am getting the file name in `zipFile.AddFile`.

```
System.IO.MemoryStream ms1 = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
System.IO.StreamWriter writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(ms1, Encoding.UTF8);

string strHeader = "";
if (FailedErrorLogList != null && FailedErrorLogList.Any())
{
   strHeader += "file_name" + ",";
   strHeader += "mobile_no" + ",";
   strHeader += "Description" + ",";
   writer.WriteLine(strHeader);
   foreach (Transactionapierrorfailedlog ErrorLog in FailedErrorLogList)
   {
      string strRowValue = "";
      strRowValue += Escape(ErrorLog.file_name) + ",";

      strRowValue += Escape(ErrorLog.mobile_no) + ",";

      strRowValue += Escape(ErrorLog.Description) + ",";

      writer.WriteLine(strRowValue);
      // writer2.WriteLine(strRowValue);
   }
   writer.Flush();
   ms1.Position = 0;
}

String filename = "Hello.csv";

if (FailedErrorLogList != null && FailedErrorLogList.Any())
{
   ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile();
   using (zipFile)
   {
      zipFile.AddFile(filename);
      zipFile.Save("Hello.zip");

   }
}
```

Comment: Try specifying full path of the Hello.csv

Comment: This is a dynamically created file.

Comment: I'm not sure that the ZipFile class is used in this way, have a look here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.zipfile.aspx

PS : link edited, now in eng

Comment: @WannyMiarelli: It's probably another class (maybe DotNetZip).

Comment: @JeffRSon i think so, but it is not specified. Tell us what library you're using, it would help.

Comment: @Dezler: Could be a dynamically created file. But, how does the compiler know from which location should it fetch the file? You could check the code by specifying an absolute path..

Comment: @Dezler: Are you using a custom ZipFile class? .NET 4.5 seems to support a static ZipFile class! If you could tell more about the ZipFile class, this could lead to the source of the error.

Answer (score 0):

The "current directory" of your service process is not what you expect it to be (in fact, it's most probably not the path of your .exe - it may be something like `c:\windows\system32` instead). You always need to specify exactly (absolute path) where you want to create the file and from where do you want to read.

Comment: Thanks JeffRSon for reply.I am creating the csv file and i have kept it in memory stream.Is there any way to sort it out..

Comment: Where exactly are you having problems?

Answer (score 0):

Use `System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath` instead of `Enviroment.CurrentDirectory`